# Searching All Directories with SearchOption.AllDirectories

Tags: c#

this is my code below. I've already created a filter that searches for any all image file extensions but when my code runs the `SearchOption.AllDirectories` appears to be trying to open a particular path instead of searching all my directories.

Anyone help me on where I've gone wrong here?

```
string[] filters = { "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.bmp" };
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(lblText.Text);
var files = new List<FileInfo>();

foreach (var filter in filters)
{
    var results = directory.GetFiles(filter, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    files.AddRange(results);
}
```

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Exactly what is `filter` set to?

Comment: I've updated my code window.

Comment: Ahh, so now I have to ask: what specifically is the value of `lblText.Text`? If it's "" then this won't work for you (it will only search the current working directory and its subdirectories)

Comment: Thank you. I've solved it with all of your help. I think I was just being an idiot. :)

Comment: You should really make an effort to write a full, complete and small question.  `lblText.Text` is just uninformative; you could easily use a string literal instead.  Maybe avoid using `var` as we don't have intelisense on StackOverflow.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: the constructor of `DirectoryInfo` doesn't accept an empty string("The path is not of a legal form.").

Answer (score 2):

I assume `directory` is a `DirectoryInfo` object and you're using [this overload of `GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327.aspx). Then a `FileInfo[]` is returned **from the current directory** matching the given search pattern and  searching all **subdirectories**.

So the directory-path of the `DirectoryInfo` is the root directory.

For example:

```
DirectoryInfo imageDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\Images");
FileInfo[] allJPGImages = imageDir.GetFiles(".jpg",  SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

**Edit** according to your edit.

So the *particular* path is the `Text` entered/shown in `lblText`. Another way to get all files with these extensions:

```
string[] filters = { "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.bmp" };
List<FileInfo> files = filters
    .SelectMany(filter => directory.EnumerateFiles(filter, System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    .ToList();
```

which does not need to load all files into memory until it starts processing. when you are working with many files and directories, [`EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx) can be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what filter is in your code, but here is a simple example to search a directory.

```
            string path = "C:\\myFolder1\\myFolder2";
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            FileInfo[] files;               
            files = dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Maybe your path is wrong?
But the AllDirectories options begins at your specified path.

Comment: Thank you. I've solved it with all of your help. I think I was just being an idiot. :)