# How to limit directory searching to a number?

Tags: vb.net

I've got some experience with C# but I'm quite new to VB.

My problem is as follows:
I want to make a simple program in VB that searches in a specific directory, for a .dft file.
I can't wrap my head around it about how I should do this.

Ultimately, I want something like this:

```vb
Dim inputdir = "C:\MyAwesomeFolder\test.par"
```

Depth / level search: **X**

**X** is the input level search limit.

```vb
For Each saveAsLocation In FormMain.documentRows 'i fetch the filename from here'

    For Each foundDirectory As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(saveAsLocation.Filename, "*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        For x As Integer = 0 To LoadedSettings.DraftSearchValue Step 1 'i fetch the int limit from here'
            For Each nestedDirectory In foundDirectory
                Dim foundFiles = Directory.GetFiles(nestedDirectory)
                For Each file In foundFiles
                    If file.EndsWith(".dft") Then
                        listOfSaveAsLocations.Add(file) 'public string list'
                    End If
                Next

            Next
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Ihe code stops at `foundDirectory` saying that the directory is invalid, which is expected as it needs a directory and not a file
but I don't know how I would go around this.

I've also got an aching feeling I'm using way too many loops for this.

I also tried some good examples
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.searchoption?view=net-7.0

(C# example)
[Searching All Directories with SearchOption.AllDirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569243/searching-all-directories-with-searchoption-alldirectories)

but I don't know how I would implement their method and the exact reason as to why.

EDIT: now with counter

```
For Each saveAsLocation In FormMain.documentRows
    counter = 0
    For Each foundDirectory As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(Path.GetDirectoryName(saveAsLocation.Filename), "*.*", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        For Each nestedDirectory In foundDirectory

            counter += 1
            If counter > LoadedSettings.DraftSearchValue Then
                Exit For
            End If

            Dim di As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(foundDirectory)
            Dim directories As DirectoryInfo() = di.GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
            Dim files As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles(".dft", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        Next


    Next
Next
```

went from SearchOption.AllDirectories to SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly, but now a new problem has arisen: instead of iterating through the current directory to go deeper, it does the opposite instead—now it goes out of the given directory to read all others.

Comment: Maybe `Dim inputdir = "C:\MyAwesomeFolder"` then? Or use `Dim inputdir = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath)`. and btw. the `For x` adds another loop to the existing ones and does not limit them.

Comment: thanks for the Path.GetDirectoryName it really did help me out there.

Comment: but if i can't limit them with a for-loop (for-each loop doesn't work either i think) how would i do this?

Comment: Is this one of the rare occasions where a do-while is applicable?

Comment: Or you can have a counter variable you update manually `counter += 1` and `If counter > limit Then Exit For End If`.

Comment: alright so i've done just that + some code adjustments of my own but now it ironically starts reading in the opposite direction

Comment: I think that the directories and files are not returned in a particular order. You must sort them if you need a particular order. Also note that [GetDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories) has a search option that let you recurse sub-directories, so that you will not have to call `GetDirectories` again inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

#### .NET Core 2.1 and later

There is an [overload of the Directory.EnumerateFiles method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=net-7.0#system-io-directory-enumeratefiles(system-string-system-string-system-io-enumerationoptions)) which allows you to specify some enumeration options, in this case we are interested in the [MaxRecursionDepth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumerationoptions), for example:

```
Dim eo = New EnumerationOptions With {.RecurseSubdirectories = True,
                                      .MaxRecursionDepth = 2}

Dim ff = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\temp", "*.txt", eo).ToList()
```

(Of course, you don't *have* to do the `.ToList()` at that point.)

#### .NET Framework

You can adapt the code from [Recursive File Search in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44104497/1115360) to limit the recursion depth:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class SomeMeaningfulName

    Public Shared Function GetSomeFiles(rootDir As String, extn As String, maxDepth As Integer) As List(Of String)
        Dim files As New List(Of String)
        GetSomeFilesHelper(rootDir, "*" & extn, maxDepth + 1, files)

        Return files

    End Function

    Private Shared Sub GetSomeFilesHelper(dir As String, extn As String, depthRemaining As Integer, files As List(Of String))
        files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(dir, extn))
        depthRemaining -= 1
        If depthRemaining > 0 Then
            For Each d In Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir)
                GetSomeFilesHelper(d, extn, depthRemaining, files)
            Next
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

You might want to add the exception handling back in, as shown in the answer I linked to. (And maybe upvote that answer.)